# instance of in Javascript, using a variable on RHS

Tags: javascript, instanceof

I am wondering if the following is allowed.

```
var abc2 = document.getElementById('T1').value;

alert((fruits instanceof abc2));

document.getElementById('T2').value = fruits instanceof abc2;
```

Can instanceof have a variable used on right hand side, instead of just string etc?

Comment: [No](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof). `instanceof` takes an Object Constructor as the right side parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Javascript, [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) must take a constructor otherwise it will not behave correctly. If you wish to check if they come from the same constructor you could try `fruits instanceof abc2.constructor`.

Comment: @ImranJ Because on Stack Overflow, we say "thanks" by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.